# Difference between file.is_open() and file.fail()

Tags: c++, file, error-handling

Initialization of `file`:

```
ifstream file("filename.txt");
```

What's is the difference between `if ( file.is_open() )` and `if (! file.fail() )` ?

What Should I use to make sure if the file is ready for I/O ?

We assume that variable `file` contains a object of a file stream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between file.is_open() and file.fail()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640847/difference-between-file-is-open-and-file-fail)

Comment: how did you get this File object?  usually C++ relies on file descriptors as ints or file streams as FILE* and methods like open, or fopen.  What libs are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it has been posted twice :( I have marked the other question for deleting.

Comment: @SB: I edited my question to clarify the origin of the variable `file`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_open()` returns true if a previous call to `open()` succeeded and there has been no intervening call to `close()`. In your example, `open()` is called from the constructor.

`fail()` returns true if `failbit` or `badbit` is set in `rdstate`.

`failbit` generally means that a conversion failed. For example, you tried to read an integer, but the next character is a letter. The stream is ok; you could read a character next and it would succeed. You would not expect the `failbit` to be set right after opening a file.

`badbit` is set when the stream is corrupt and the next operation will fail.

Answer (score 1):

.is_open tells you that the file is open and ready to be used.  .fail is most likely used to indicate that a previous operation (eg a read) has failed.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the origin of the variable `file`. Thanks